# Is the initialization of an element a side effect of the initializer-clause?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, operator-precedence, aggregate-initialization

In paragraph 8.6.4p4 of [N4606](http://open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf), we have:

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the
>   *initializer-clauses*,
>   ..., are evaluated in the
>   order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and side effect
>   associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value
>   computation and side effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that
>   follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*.

In this program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   int a[4] = { ++i, ++i, ++i,    // These are OK.
     accumulate(begin(a), end(a)-1, 0, plus<int>())  // Is this well-defined?
   };
   copy(begin(a), end(a), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

It is clear that `accumulate` is evaluated after the expressions `++i`, and
the side-effects of `++i` are sequenced and well-defined.
But is the initialization of an array element with the result of `++i` also a side-effect of an *initializer-clause*? Does `accumulate` read out the values 1, 2, and 3, or does it potentially access uninitialized values?